# my API request is looping until the server send an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I'm trying to get my top listened artists on spotify with the spotify API using reactjs and the [spotify-web-api-node](https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node) package. I also use the useState and useEffect. When I run the app the getMyTopArtists function run in loop until it gets a 426 status code, that means that the rate limit is reached.
How can I fix this bug pls?

```js
const [topArtists, setTopArtists] = useState([]);
```

```js
useEffect(() => {
      if (!accessToken) return
      
      spotifyApi.getMyTopArtists({limit: 5, time_range: 'medium_term'}).then(res => {
        setTopArtists(res.body.items.map(artist => {
          return{
            name: artist.name,
            uri: artist.uri,
            cover: artist.images.uri,
            genre: artist.genres,
          }
        }))
      })
    }, [topArtists, accessToken])
```

Comment: Remove `topArtists` from the dependency array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that in your dependency array of the `useEffect` hook, you included `topArtists`. So, what is happening is that once the `accessToken` becomes truthy, you send a request to fetch your top artists. Once your artists are fetched, you update `topArtists` state value. Once `topArtists` is updated (due to the dependency array), the `useEffect` runs again, updates State again, so on and so forth.

While I'm not the absolute expert on it, it is likely that React is not performing deep comparison for the array of objects, so even if the value is identical, it registers it as "it changed".

The solution in this case is simple --> just remove `topArtists` from your dependency array.

Alternatively, you could consider 2 other methods:

1. in the same way you are doing `if (!accessToken) return` you can do `if (topArtists.length) return` to not fetch again if fetched once. Similarly, you can set the state's initial value to something like null and do `if (!topArtists) spotifyApi....`.
2. instead of this `useEffect` hook, you might be able to attach this functionality as a `.then` to wherever you are obtaining the `accessToken`. If you are sending a login request to Spotify and receiving the token in the response, you can do something like

```js
spotifyApi.login({details}).then(res => {
  const {accessToken:myToken} = res;
  setAccessToken(myToken);
  return myToken;
}).then(token => {
   //recommended to use the token here since setState is not instant
  spotifyApi.getMyTopArtists({limit: 5, time_range: 'medium_term'}).then(res 
   => {
        setTopArtists(res.body.items.map(artist => {
          return{
            name: artist.name,
            uri: artist.uri,
            cover: artist.images.uri,
            genre: artist.genres,
          }
        }))
   }
```